QGIS Atlas - show child features of adjacent parents
In my QGIS project, I want to create an atlas layout. I have a 1:n relation set up (both layers have an index1 field which acts as primary/foreign key) between my parcel and my owner table. The layout should not only contain information about the current atlas feature, but also some information about the owners of the neighbouring (touching) features. With a small subdataset I was successful in setting the item properties of the table to:
Source: Layer Features (Table owners)
And add the following filter: array_contains( aggregate(layer:= 'parcels', aggregate:='array_agg', expression:= "index1", filter:=overlay_touches($geometry, geometry(@atlas_feature))),"index1")
But using this filter continuously crashes (freezes) my QGIS - both layers hold 5-7000 features and I guess the query just takes too long. Does anyone have a better idea how to filter the owner table to show only entries of features neighbouring the original atlas feature?

I had similar problems with large datasets. When using the geometry based functions I think QGIS is doing that operation on all features to test if they touch the atlas feature. If your parcels don't change much I think the best solution might be to calculate each parcels neighbour as an attribute and use that to get the information in the atlas. QGIS is much better at reading the table than doing geographical analysis on the fly.

yes, that sounds an reasonable analysis of the problem - having a look on the postgres server while qgis was doing the filtering, it showed alot of workload. i solved it with joining the mappable parcel layer to the (non mappable) owner table. The result layer is hidden in map canvas - in the atlas, the attribute table option is set to "show only features intersecting the atlas feature". This feels more like a workaround though :(
